# Create a record with Associations in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am working on a project and relatively new to Golang. I am using `GORM` for my Database ORM. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I can't get to create records with associations.

```golang
type (
    Task struct {
        gorm.Model
        Title       string    `json:"title"`
        Description string    `json:"description"`
        Priority    Priority  `json:"priority_id" validate:"required" gorm:"foreignkey:PriorityID"`
        PriorityID  uint
    }

    Priority struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name      string     `json:"name"`
    }
)
```

And when I do

```golang
task := Task{
    Title:       "Test Task!",
    Description: "Test Task Description",
    Priority:    Priority{ID: 1},
}
db.Create(&task)
```

It throws me this error:

> [2019-07-27 18:34:35]  sql: converting argument $7 type:
>   unsupported type models.Priority, a struct

I had a look at [GORM Associations](http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html) but couldn't really find any solution which could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think im late to answer but looking at the error its a issue with the Priority struct.

and i think you dont have to mention the foreign key ( i assume gorm would take it ) so you can easily fix this by removing the foreign key and just letting gorm select one and it should work fine

here's my example

```golang
type Task struct {
        gorm.Model
        Title       string
        Description string
        Priority    Priority
        PriorityID  uint
}

type Priority struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name string
}

func main() {
        db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
        if err != nil {
                panic("failed to connect database")
        }

        db.AutoMigrate(&Task{}, &Priority{})

        task := Task{
                Title:       "Test Task!",
                Description: "Test Task Description",
                Priority:    Priority{ID: 1},
        }
        db.Create(&task)

        var tasks []Task
        db.Joins("Priority").Find(&tasks)
        fmt.Println(tasks)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Gorm is and object-relational mapping (ORM) framework for Go.
To create a record with association use something like this:

```
type (
    Task struct {
        Title       string    `gorm:"column:title"`
        Description string    `gorm:"column:description"`
        PriorityID  int64     `gorm:"column:priority_id"`
        Priority    Priority  `gorm:"foreignkey:PriorityID"`
    }

    Priority struct {
        ID        int64      `gorm:"primary_key"`
        Name      string     `gorm:"column:name"`
    }
)
```

Then try to add

```
task := Task{
    Title:       "Test Task!",
    Description: "Test Task Description",
    Priority:    Priority{ID: 1},
}
db.Create(&task)
```

Please use this link for refer :
[Gorm Documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html)